# Abbreviations on tennis tournaments

Tags: tennis, tournaments, atp

Abbreviations on tennis tournamentss. I know LL (lucky loser), SE (special exempt) , PR (protected), W (wild card), Q (qualifier), but now there is (O) appearing next to names. What is (O) qualifying for tourneys?

Comment: Welcome to [sports.se]! Do you have an example you can link to?

Answer (score 1):

There is no (O) abbreviation, at least not in English. Maybe you meant WO or W/O which means, that player advanced to the next round via walkover. Walkover means, that opponent has retired from the match even before it started.